# Adding a second PanGestureRecognizer, or equivalent workaround?

Tags: ios, ios-charts

I'm working with the [`ios-charts`](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library and I need to do some special logic when the user stops panning over the chart. The library defines the `panGestureRecognized` method as fileprivate, so I can't subclass/override it. It also doesn't provide any sort of protocol for listening to the pan gestures.

How can I listen to the pan gestures without interrupting the functionality of the chart?

I've considered putting a view on top of the chart and adding a gesture recognizer to *that*, but it swallows the events and disrupts the regular chart functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of any gesture recognizer is to block touches to its subviews. You can change this behavior by writing:

```
panGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

To get even more control over simultaneous pan gesture gesture recognition, set your own class as the delegate for the gesture recognizer and use this method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

Just return `YES` in this method if you just care about the two pan gestures to work simultaneously.

Comment: So `panGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false` was not working for me, but making myself the delegate and allowing simultaneous recognition did the trick. Thanks!